# Handle absence of JNDI

Tags: java, spring, jndi

I have configured JNDI reference in spring

```
<bean id="optionalBean" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="name"/>
</bean>
```

But this JNDI property could be not configured. In this case my Tomcat doesn't start.
How can I tell Spring that this JNDI is optional?

Update:
After adding `lookupOnStartup` I get the error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'optionalBean': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'optionalBean' while setting bean property 'optionalBean'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'optionalBean': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot deactivate 'lookupOnStartup' without specifying a 'proxyInterface' or 'expectedType'
```

Comment: If its not required during spring context startup, you can provide a property "lookupOnStartup" and its value to false. It skips looking for the jndi on startup. Attempts to find it is only when it is first used.

Comment: [From the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html#setLookupOnStartup-boolean-)

Comment: @CodeItLikeAmeen It shows me the error. Please see updated question

Comment: What services/resources are you trying to represent via JNDI? A datasource? You can specify the proxy interface class with <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/> Or whatever type the optionalBean is expected to be with "expectedType" property.

Comment: @CodeItLikeAmeen I'm trying to represent the url to service, so it's just plain String

Comment: Then add <property name="expectedType" value="java.lang.String"/>

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
 <bean id="optionalBean" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
            <property name="jndiName" value="name"/>
        </bean>
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I'm still getting the error: 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [name].